# How to show only the TeX boxes

Tags: boxes

I'd like to use a sequence of boxes to show how TeX works. I read some time ago that everything (or almost) in TeX are boxes.

So, how to show only the TeX boxes that surround each character, each line, each paragraph?

I'd like something similar to the image below, not `fbox` which contains blank space around it.

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a separation length for `fbox`?

Comment: There is `\fboxsep` but I'll need to use `\fbox` around every character.

Comment: That can probably be arranged via a recursive solution. I do wish I had my computer these days...

Comment: There is probably a smarter way though.

Comment: At one point in time, I convinced someone to write a utility which parsed a log file and created a .pdf which showed all of the boxes. Wish I'd kept up w/ it.

Comment: @WillAdams, I'd like to see the page full of boxes, only the boxes.

Comment: For an inspiration, you can see Exercise 11.5 in Chapter **11 Boxes** (page 67) of the *TeXbook* and its solution in Appendix A, pages 310-311. There, Knuth defines a `\demobox` command.

Answer (score 7):

In Exercise 11.5 (Chapter **11 Boxes**) on page 67 of the *TeXbook* Knuth proposes the definition of a `\demobox` command; in Appendix A, pages 310-311, Knuth presents the solution. The solution is not complete for the problem presented in this question (macros and accented characters, for example, don't behave as expected), but it's an interesting code and valid as a partial answer. Since I simply transcribe it here, I make this answer CW with all credit to D.E. Knuth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\dolist{\afterassignment\dodolist\let\next= }
\def\dodolist{\ifx\next\endlist \let\next\relax
\else \\\let\next\dolist \fi
\next}
\def\endlist{\endlist}
\def\hidehrule#1#2{\kern-#1%
\hrule height#1 depth#2 \kern-#2 }
\def\hidevrule#1#2{\kern-#1{\dimen0=#1
\advance\dimen0 by#2\vrule width\dimen0}\kern-#2 }
\def\makeblankbox#1#2{\hbox{\lower\dp0\vbox{\hidehrule{#1}{#2}%
\kern-#1 % overlap the rules at the corners
\hbox to \wd0{\hidevrule{#1}{#2}%
\raise\ht0\vbox to #1{}% set the vrule height
\lower\dp0\vtop to #1{}% set the vrule depth
\hfil\hidevrule{#2}{#1}}%
\kern-#1\hidehrule{#2}{#1}}}}
\def\maketypebox{\makeblankbox{0pt}{1pt}}
\def\makelightbox{\makeblankbox{.2pt}{.2pt}}
\def\\{\if\space\next\ % assume that \next is unexpandable
\else \setbox0=\hbox{\next}\maketypebox\fi}
\def\demobox#1{#1~\setbox0=\hbox{\dolist#1\endlist}%
\leavevmode\copy0\kern-\wd0\makelightbox\par}

\begin{document}

\demobox{Test}
\demobox{Some Other Words}
\demobox{\TeX :-(}% doesn't produce the desired result
%\demobox{Céfiro}% fails

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I dont think this is a perfect solution for the question. Since, the question seems to be interesting, one way to achieve it manually:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt

\makeatletter
\def\boxit#1{%
   \fboxsep=0pt%
   \fboxrule=.1pt%
   \@tfor\xx:=#1\do{%
       \fbox{\phantom{\xx}}%
   } #1%
}

\boxit{Grupa}\\
\boxit{U{\.z}ytkownik{\'o}w}\\
\boxit{Systemu}\\
\boxit{\TeX}  %This wont work ;-(

\end{document}
```

Here, if we pass macros, then it will, for example `\boxit{\TeX}` will appear in single box rather than in three boxes. Also, for accented characters we need to group it like `{\'a}` or `{\'{a}}`. Another problem is that, we need to put the box manually.